# Reactjs list of items created with react-redux connect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The item code is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const init = (bindProps,bindAction) => {
  //@connect does not work with pre processor and/or transpiler
  class Item extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>status: {this.props.item.status}</div>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.approveItem(this.props.index)}>Approve </button>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.disApproveItem(this.props.index)}>DisApprove </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
  return connect(bindProps, bindAction)(Item);
};
export default init;
```

In my app I try this:

```
const Items = 
  <ul>{
    store.getState().items.map(
      itemState=>{
        const Item = initItem(
          state => state.items[itemState.index],
          wrapDispatch(
            "ITEM"
          )(
            itemActions
          )(
            (a,b,c,d,e)=>console.log("ok",a,b,c,d,e)||store.getState().items[0]
          )
        );
        console.log("item is now:",Item);
        return <Item key={itemState.index}/>
      }
    )
  }</ul>

//...
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Items />
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Resulting in error:

> > Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

The Item in both working and not working case is the connect function in `/node_modules/react-redux/es/components/connectAdvanced.js`

The following does work though:

```
const Item = initItem(
  state => state.items[0],
  wrapDispatch(
    "ITEM"
  )(itemActions)(
    (a,b,c,d,e)=>console.log("ok",a,b,c,d,e)&&store.getState().items[0]
  )
);
const Item2 = initItem(
  state => state.items[1],
  wrapDispatch(
    "ITEM"
  )(itemActions)(
    (a,b,c,d,e)=>console.log("ok",a,b,c,d,e)&&store.getState().items[1]
  )
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ul><Item /><Item2 /></ul>
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**update**

Thanks to sameeh I changed Items to a function:

```
const Items = () =>
  <ul>{
    store.getState().items.map(
      itemState=>{
        const Item = initItem(
          state => state.items[itemState.index],
          wrapDispatch(
            "ITEM"
          )(
            itemActions
          )(
            ()=>itemState
          )
        );
        return <Item key={itemState.index}/>
      }
    )
  }</ul>
```

Full (unfinished) code [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/react-component-isolation), will try to document writing a component that can be fully autonomous (consumer delegates actions to it) still passes all actions to consumer so consumer can optionally act on certain actions and does not need [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/combinereducers) because as I understand it combineReducers does not deal with possible naming conflicts for action.type, `getState` for thunk actions or wrapping the component action into an action handled or delegated by the consumer (consumer can easily identify what component dispatched the action as the action is wrapped by consumer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says everything. You have something like:

```
const Items = <ul>...</ul>
```

Which won't work. A React component is a `class` or a `function`. It needs to be like:

```
const Items = () => <ul>...</ul>
```